# twoside introduces incorrect linespacing at end of section

Tags: spacing, floats, vertical-alignment, double-sided

I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
```

with no special customisation.

In one page, at the end of a section, I have a big figure with two paragraphs of text below it, and these two paragraphs are not enough to fill up the rest of the page.

When I use the `\documentclass` as above I get some extra white space at the end of the page, which is fine: the vertical spacing from the figure caption and between the two paragraphs is standard and correct.

But if I switch to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
```

I get extra blank space between the figure caption and the 1st paragraph and also between the 1st and 2nd paragraph.

I want to use `twoside` to set the headings with `fancyhdr`. How can I get rid of these ugly white spaces?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use `twoside` you get `flushbuttom` as standard. Try using the command `\raggedbottom` in your preamble.

Also, I suggest using the package `footmisc` with the option `bottom` if you have footnotes in your document. Put the line

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

in you preamble and the footnotes lines up at the bottom of the page.

Comment: As the *question* is not about `footmisc`, I removed the respective tag.

Comment: @lockstep I disagree. An annoying side effect of `\raggedbottom` is the various high of the footnotes. In my opinion, when we recommend `\raggedbottom`, we should mention that side effect and how to avoid it. So, the tag is informative and should not be deleted. When I click on a tag, I assume to see all references, both in the question and in the answer. If this is not the ‘policy’, I suggest a change.

Comment: In that case, read http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/whats-the-policy-on-retagging-questions-based-on-answers for starters.

Comment: @lockstep I cannot see any authoritative conclusion or reference in that tread authorising anybody to delete others re-tagging. Enough said.