# Twoside latex document-class changes spacing behaviour between text and environments

Tags: spacing, environments, double-sided

I changed my document from `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}` to `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}` and after I recompiled the document, the spacing between e.g. some text and a `table` environment changed. This is the LaTeX code for creating the table with its content:

```
beschrieben (vgl. Listing \ref{lst:applicationproperties}, Zeile 2-7): \\

\begin{table}[H]
    \sffamily
    \begin{center}
        {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
            \hline
            -------CONTENT OF TABLE--------
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}} \quad
    \end{center}
    \caption{Properties einer Spring Datasource} 
\end{table}

Für eine Übersicht aller von Spring Data spezifizierten Properties, bietet die \cite[offizielle Dokumentation von Spring Boot]{spdata:04} eine gute Referenz.
```

The following two pictures show the issue pretty good I think. Before I changed the `doucmentclass`, the spacing looked like this:

[image: Picture before changing the documentclass]

After the change, the spacing almost doubled and it looks like the text is placed at the very bottom of the page:

[image: Picture after changing the documentclass]

I am pretty sure it is not a big problem behind it, but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for that problem yet. Does somebody know what is wrong there?

Comment: A `twoside` class automatically uses flushbottom to make sure the last row of text on each side ends up at the same height. You could try `\raggedbottom` to disable this.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77809/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62572/134144 are related

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I needed!